# If /etc/sysctl.conf doesn't exist, where is my sysctl storing configs?

Tags: arch-linux, sysctl, magic-sysrq

I want to change two values using sysctl. One is the `sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and the other, `sysctl kernel.sysrq=1`. However, when I run `sysctl -p`, it tells me `sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.conf": No such file or directory`, but `sysctl -a` returns [this](https://pastebin.com/iUxAAm0k).
So, I want to ask where is my system storing sysctl config?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The configuration has long moved to `/etc/sysctl.d/*`

You can create individual files, e.g.

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/swappiness.conf

vm.swappiness=10
```

As for the `sysctl -a` output - you're seeing the current kernel values.

Comment: And ```sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/swappiness.conf```? Will this make it permanent?

Comment: This command will activate the setting for the current session, and on reboot Arch Linux boot scripts will do that automatically, so, yes, it will make it permanent.